# Changing views programmatically

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I know there are a lot of posts about this but my problem is a bit different. I have a Tab Bar Controller with multiple views and one of the views is the Login View, if the user does Login it should change the view to present the User menu.

At the same time i need to keep the Tab Bar menu visible, so i can't use modal since it will loose the reference to the Tab Bar Controller.

So i ended up using a Navigation Controller where i just push the User Menu view into the stack (not the best way but it works).

The problem is, if the user double click on the Login Bar it will load the Login View, and i don't want this to happen.

[image]

On this example, if the user clicks on the Login button it will go to the Blue view, but if the user double click on the Feature Button on the Tab Bar Menu it will go to the red view.

Since my solution does not work how can i achieve what i want? If the user press the Login button it will ONLY show the Blue view until he press the Logout button.

[Edit]

Here is the code to show the blue view:

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

let ViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "userViewID") as! UserViewController
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ViewController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok i ended up checking if the Navigation Controller had more than one child (for the red one) and removing the first child from the navigation array so it could dealloc it and show only the one i wanted.

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        if((self.navigationController?.viewControllers.count)! > 1)
        {
            self.navigationController?.viewControllers.removeFirst()
        }
    }
```

The reason i ended up doing this was because clicking 2x on the Tab Bar item it would bring me to the red view even if i had already pushed the blue view to the Navigation array.